# Using Interop.Visio dll always opening visio application in Frontend

Tags: c#, interop, office-interop, visio

Hi i was trying to open Visio using **interop assembley** in c#.
While trying to open the document by below code

```
visio.Application app = new visio.Application();
```

it opens a application in the frontEnd also.But i dont want to open in frontend .I simply need to get the application stuffs while doing programatically.

namespace am using **using visio=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;**.

But if i opened Excel or Word it dosent open me the application in the frontEnd.I need the visio to behave the same as the Word and excel does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Visio.InvisibleApp instead Of Visio.Application.

Comment: It works cool Thanks man..!! But can you please tell me why Visio is not behaving like Excel , Word..?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a new Application instance in the add-in. Instead, you can use the Application property of the add-in class.

Comment: Actually Sorry ..I have updated my question.As i said , need to open Visio using c#, Not from Addin class